# How to display clusters of optics algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot, optics-algorithm

I used optics.m function from http://chemometria.us.edu.pl/download/OPTICS.M to calculate optics algorithm in MATLAB. This function outputs RD and CD and Order vector of all points. 
I used `bar(RD(order));` code to display Reachability plot of them. But I want to index clusters of points and scatter them in MATLAB. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that code. It is slow, and I read somewhere here that it is even giving incorrect results?

But most of all, it lacks cluster extraction functionality; it is only half of OPTICS.

Comment: so, how can i extraxt clusters in matlab with optics algorithm?

Comment: I'm not aware of any complete OPTICS except the one in ELKI.